# Accessing initramfs-tools features in Yocto generated initramfs image

Tags: initramfs, sysvinit, initrd, yocto, plymouth

I would like to load a few kernel modules, and activate framebuffer access prior to Plymouth launch. This is normally done using `/etc/initramfs-tools` directory provided with the `initramfs-tools`. However, when building an initramfs image with Yocto, no such directory is available. This means that whatever `initramfs-tools` does for loading modules and initializing framebuffer, has to be done manually in the `initramfs` image as far as I could understand.

The tasks I want to accomplish is very delicately explained by notro in https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Bootsplash
. I'd like to do the equivalent of what's done below:

- Access to `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/spi` and `modprobe` a module.
- Access to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and list further modules to be launched by modules daemon
- Enable framebuffer which is done via `echo "export FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/fb1`

With my research, I could find [initramfs-framework-base package](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/tree/master/meta/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-framework) which features some scripts that initramfs boot uses. I think this might be a good starting point. However, I do not know how to explicitly tell initramfs to do what I want to accomplish (tasks above).

**Note:** Currently, my initramfs image is generated by the following recipe:

```
include recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb
BASEPACKS = " \
    base-passwd \
    busybox \
    initramfs-live-boot \
    initramfs-framework-base \
    udev \
    ${ROOTFS_BOOTSTRAP_INSTALL} \
"

IMAGE_INSTALL = " ${BASEPACKS} \
                  plymouth plymouth-set-default-theme  \
                "

# Do not pollute the initrd image with rootfs features
IMAGE_FEATURES = "splash"
SPLASH = "plymouth"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE = "8192"
IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR = "1.0"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "0"
IMAGE_ROOTFS_MAXSIZE = "12288"

CMDLINE_append = " quiet splash nomodeset plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles consoleblank=0"

BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS += "busybox-syslog"
```

**Also Note:** I'm using an ARMv6-based machine with U-boot bootloader. Compiling the original `initramfs-tools` (that is originally developed for Debian) generates 0 byte images. I'm guessing this is an issue with its compatibility. So I'll have to resort to generating initramfs with yocto's internal tools.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont find a yocto solution, you might be able to just concatenate a 2nd cpio of the wanted files to the image, as mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243657/119298).

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to do the exact same thing. Thank you.